# Static Functions in Dart - Calling just once

Tags: dart, flutter

I have created a service class to read a JSON file and store it's content in a Class.

```
  static getAllKurals() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await _parseJsonFromAssets();
    return Response.fromJsonMap(data);
  }

  static Future<Kural> getRandomKural() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = await _parseJsonFromAssets();
    Response response = Response.fromJsonMap(data);

    return Future<Kural>.value(response.kurals[getRandomKuralNumber()]);
  }
```

I have several such methods to deal with the data.

The problem is that ever function reads the data every time. Is it possible to make the service read the file just once and use it's Map available to all functions? I am not sure what this is called in Dart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  static Map<String, dynamic> _allKuralsCache;
  static getAllKurals() async {
    Map<String, dynamic> data = _allKuralsCache ?? await _parseJsonFromAssets();
    return Response.fromJsonMap(data);
  }
```

or to also avoid `Response.fromJsonMap(...)` to be called every time

```
  static Response _allKuralsCache;
  static getAllKurals() async {
    if(_dataResponseCache == null) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = _dataCache ?? await _parseJsonFromAssets();
      _dataResponseCache = Response.fromJsonMap(data);
    }
    return _dataResponseCache; 
  }
```